# Deploy App_Data folder to Azure Insufficient Permissions

Tags: azure, permissions, web-deployment, app-data

I am running VS2015 as Administrator.
I have deployed before with files in App_Data folder.
I have deployed this project many times to Azure with success.
After adding a .pdf file today in App_Data folder and attempting to deploy I get this error:
[image]

How do I get Azure to accept my file?  I don't understand how permissions could be a problem now when nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my project, this was the solution and the steps I took:

I have determined the error was caused by doing the following:

By using windows explorer, I copied the .pdf file into my App_Data folder.  Afterwards, within my VS solution explorer, I clicked show all files, and then selected the shadowed out .pdf file.  I right clicked and selected "Include in project".

To fix my problem:

I stayed within VS.  I right clicked on the App_Data folder and selected "Add" > "Existing Item".  Browsed to the .pdf file and hit enter.  Next, I deployed to my Azure environment successfully.